# Is there a plugin interface in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: plugins, toad

We want to get some missing functionality into Toad for Oracle. The goal is to add a menu entry that allows to access and modify the text in the editor.

Is there some documented plugin interface (like for Eclipse) to write extensions for Toad?

Answer (score 2):

Toad still (2021) lacks a Plugin API or Plugin SDK for developing extensions for Toad.

Following [official](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/toad-sdk/10575/5) and not [offical](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/toad-plugin-api/9570/3) answer from Toad's forum:

> No, we don’t provide an API for this, but Toad does support command
> line execution. That means you could call a specific function in Toad
> via the Automation Designer feature (read the Help) and perform a
> specific task.
>
> Take a look at the Toad Help on Command Line Syntax and Execute
> Actions from the Command Line and let me know if this helps.

It sounds a little ironic because Now Toad itself has [developed](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/toad-plugin-for-ssms/50098) a Plugin for Microsoft SSMS. And it means that Toad uses Plugin API of other software extensively, not providing API itself.